# array in where condition in laravel

Tags: laravel

hello i am facing problem in where condition laravel.
i have two array

```
$a = [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 9
  2 => 39
  3 => 174
  4 => 190
];

$b = [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 9
  2 => 39
  3 => 174
  4 => 190
  5 => 0
];

**array values is ids.  i tried array_values($a) && array_values($b) 
i want ids like this  but not get same response.**

[ 2 ,9 ,39 ,174 ,190] && [ 2 ,9 ,39 ,174 ,190 , 0 ]
```

trying to get data from query like

```
$classrooms = Classroom::where('teacher_id', $teacherId)
                ->where('school_curriculum_id', [$b])
                ->where('hybrid_curriculum', [$b])->get();
```

but got null . something wrong in where condition.
please help me to solve this.

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'school_id', 'grade_id', 'teacher_id', 'school_curriculum_id', 'name', 'deleted', 'deleted_date', 'archived', 'is_hybrid', 'hybrid_curriculum', 'hybrid_grade', 'enable_auto_submit_assessment', 'timeline_type', 'timeline_modified', 'group_test_by', 'created', 'modified', 'enable_auto_lockout_unit',
    ];
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: have  you  tried whereIn instead of where?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$classrooms = Classroom::where('teacher_id', $teacherId)
                ->whereIn('school_curriculum_id', $b)
                ->whereIn('hybrid_curriculum', $b)->get();
```